# Changing automatic indentation for Ruby in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting, indentation

When using Sublime Text 3, and typing in Ruby, when I type:

```
testing = {
}
```

And then I type any character, such as a comma after the `}`, then that line will automatically indent by one level, so that it results like this:

```
testing = {

  },
```

How can I stop it from automatically indenting?

Comment: First of all, I want to commisserate with you. I also find this super annoying. You can disable it by turning `"auto_indent": false` in your user settings. However you will lose all auto indenting, such as what happens with methods inside a class block, etc. I would be curious to know if there is a way to disable this particular case of indentation, without removing the others.

Comment: which version of Sublime Text 3 are you using? this seems to work out the box with [build 3156 and the shipped Ruby syntax](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/05d7e343dfa9060d911ed1763c2d53acd9141354/Ruby/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences#L11) (comma after `}` doesn't prevent unindentation) - maybe you have installed a package that overrides the default indentation behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the latest Stable version of Sublime Text 3. If I install the latest dev version, then the problem is fixed. It was fixed in a relatively recent dev version of the app.